# How to interact with COM objects using C?

Tags: c, windows

I wanted to interact COM objects using C (specifically the Word object) but how could I do this?

Comment: n.b. the accepted answer there also has links the rest of the article series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [COM in Plain C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C). It illustrates an [example C program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C#C) consuming a COM object that was created earlier.

Comment: MAN THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'll check your answer once the checking time is enabled :D